# Null Pointer Exception if i try to create new Cell and write data into excel

Tags: java, apache, selenium

I am trying to write title and price into excel file. I am creating columns but java game me error 'NULL POINTER EXCEPTION' at line number 48, Please help me what is main reason.But if i write at line no 48 ,sheet1.getRow(0).createCell(0).getStringCellValue('Naqash');Then no Null pointer error is showing.

```
package codeclasses;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ReadExcel {

    List<WebElement> title, prices;

    @Test

    public void test() throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "h:\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://themeforest.net/search/education?referrer=homepage&utf8=%E2%9C%93");

        title = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class = 'product-list__heading']/a"));

        prices = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p[@class='product-list__price-desktop']"));


        File src = new File("./file/Book1.xlsx");
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            int j = 0;

            if(sheet1.getRow(i+1)==null){
(48)        sheet1.getRow(i+2).createCell(j).setCellValue("Naqash");
            sheet1.getRow(i+2).createCell(j+1).setCellValue("Zafar");
            }
            else{

                System.out.println("Cant find the scene");
            }
            FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(src);
            wb.write(fileout);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the row and cell before you insert data into it. For example:

```
int rowIndex = 0;
int columnIndex = 0;
Row row = sheet1.createRow(rowIndex);
Cell cell = row.createCell(columnIndex);
cell.setCellValue("Naqash");
```

You can get row by `getRow(index)` if you have already created it before

Comment: You Made my Day, ThankYou @pomah :)

Comment: @naqash so you can accept my answer if it helped you =) Good luck!

Comment: ,yes i have done voting but my reputation is not allowing the reflection of the vote.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you never test if the cell is null!

```
if (cell == null)
{
 System.out.println("Cell is Empty in Column:" + cols);

} 
 else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
 {
 //code
 }
```

As a general matter, you should be careful while handling `Cell.getCellType()` function, since an empty cell could be either `null` or be a `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`.

I hope it helped.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i got the solution, keep helping :)